# should i remove hinges from door and door frame before painting

Tags: doors, painting

I had brand new pre-primed unpainted french doors installed and now I have to paint them (also need to paint the new door frame).  I plan to remove the doors from the door frame as well as remove the door knob but is it best practice to also remove the hinges from the door and frame before painting?
My concern is it not screwing back in cleanly once Im ready to put the hinges back on.

Comment: I have had problems unscrewing hinges from an old building, the screw holes were deteriorated and they wouldn't go back in without a lot of rework. I would be less reluctant to remove the hinges from a brand new door.

Comment: It's a lot easier to wipe the paint off if you slip and get paint on the hinge than it is to remove the hinges and reinstall them. You could mask them.

Comment: I would just pull the pins I agree with Harper. Paint under the hinge could make the hinge not fit as well and the door possibly hit the jamb if it is a tight fit. Then the possibility of messing up the holes.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I would if it's easy to remove them, but you can still do it hinges are still on. My father and I removed our hinges ,but they were easy to remove. You don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Removing hinges can very definitely lead to fit problems later. Also, it's not easy at all to balance a door while trying to screw hinges back in -- especially heavy doors, which French doors are bound to be. Do not remove them from the door. Put masking on the hinges (don't leave tape on longer than necessary) to protect them from paint -- nothing looks worse than hinges gopped with paint.

If they are split pin hinges, remove the pins, leave the hinge leaves attached to door and frame. Mark the pins so you can put them back in the same hinges.